# Selecting close button of other tab closes current tab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am creating an app where new tabs are created dynamically. I have added close button for each tab to close.

***Issue:***

If I have multiple tabs open, and I am currently in tab2, and I select close button of tab4, then tab2 get closed.
I have also used data binding of my TabControl using RelayCommand. But that also had the same issue.
Kindly suggest where I have gone wrong and what I can add in my code.

Below is my code.

XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="50" Margin="0,0,0,0.2" Width="1215" ItemsSource="{Binding Titles, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="454" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="21">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        <Button Name="BtnClose" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="16" Height="16"
          Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseTabCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tabControl1,Path=SelectedItem}" />
        <!--Click="BtnClose_Click"-->
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <RichTextBox Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <FlowDocument>
          <Paragraph FontSize="12" FontFamily="Courier New">
            <Run Text="{Binding Content}"></Run>
          </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
      </RichTextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

My ViewModel class where I create a class Tab Item *"Item"* that will hold a tab Content and header.

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public MainWindowViewModel() {
   Titles = new ObservableCollection < Item > ();
  }

  public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged {
   public string Header {
    get;
    set;
   }
   //public string Content { get; set; }
   private string _content;

   public static int _count = -1;
   public int Count {
    get {
     return _count;
    }
    set {
     _count = value; /* OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));*/
    }
   }

   public string Content {
    get {
     return _content;
    }
    set {
     _content = value;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Content));
    }
   }
   public Item() {
    _count++; //increase the count of tab. This will represent the index of the tab
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    handler ? .Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
  }
  public ObservableCollection < Item > Titles {
   get {
    return _titles;
   }
   set {
    _titles = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
   }
  }

  static int tabs = 1;
  private ObservableCollection < Item > _titles;

  private RelayCommand < Item > _closeTabCommand;
  public RelayCommand < Item > CloseTabCommand {
   get {
    return _closeTabCommand ?? (_closeTabCommand = new RelayCommand < Item > (
      (t) => {
       Titles.Remove(t);
      }));
   }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
   var handler = PropertyChanged;
   handler ? .Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
 }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  //remove tab
  MainWindowVMObj.RemoveTabItem(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close button's `CommandParameter` is passing the selected tab as the tab to be closed.

One easy fix to that is to simply bypassing the current source control of the event as a `CommandParameter` instead (which will be the parent TabItem of the targeted close button in that case):

```
<DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="21">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    <Button Name="BtnClose" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="16" Height="16"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseTabCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```